# python parse text that starts and ends with asterisks

Tags: python, regex

I have a text like this:

```
**********************************************************************
*********                                                    *********
*********     llgalfaslfjasljflksjaglajlgjlajlgfaslg         *********
*********                                                    *********
********* Key1:            value1                            *********
*********                                                    *********
********* Key2: Thu, 06.02.2020 22:28:22                     *********
*********                                                    *********
********* Key3:           Sep 30 2019-02:35:32               *********
*********                  key4: dc960e6, ttt: 35044b5       *********
*********                                                    *********
********* Key5:         Value5                               *********
*********                                                    *********
********* Key6:    Value6                                    *********
*********                                                    *********
**********************************************************************
```

I would like to write a function like:

```
def getKey(src,pattern,key):

...
```

**where:**

```
source  = the text as seen in the sample above (can be more or les )

pattern = regex pattern

key = the key I would like to get the value of
```

the result should ideally be a list of values of the key in the src

for instance:

```
Key=Key1 => [value1]

Key=Key2 => [Thu, 06.02.2020 22:28:22]

Key=Key4 => [dc960e6, ttt: 35044b5]
```

basically the value after the: while removing all the stars, spaces, ...

I do not know how to create the regex pattern for this

tried something like:

```
pattern = r'(?<=^*********).+(?=\*********$)'
```

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1):

You can use python-textops3 that is able to do many string manipulations/parsing :

```
from textops import *

s = '''
**********************************************************************
*********                                                    *********
*********     llgalfaslfjasljflksjaglajlgjlajlgfaslg         *********
*********                                                    *********
********* Key1:            value1                            *********
*********                                                    *********
********* Key2: Thu, 06.02.2020 22:28:22                     *********
*********                                                    *********
********* Key3:           Sep 30 2019-02:35:32               *********
*********                  key4: dc960e6, ttt: 35044b5       *********
*********                                                    *********
********* Key5:         Value5                               *********
*********                                                    *********
********* Key6:    Value6                                    *********
*********                                                    *********
**********************************************************************
'''
print(s | keyval(r'^\*+\s*(?P<key>\w+)\s*:\s*(?P<val>.+?)\s+\*+$'))
```

gives :

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'Thu, 06.02.2020 22:28:22', 'key3': 'Sep 30 2019-02:35:32', 'key4': 'dc960e6, ttt: 35044b5', 'key5': 'Value5', 'key6': 'Value6'}
```

But if you want to get one special kay-value like you asked : your function will be :

```
def getKey(src,pattern,key): 
    return src | find_pattern(pattern.format(key=key)) 

pattern = r'^\*+\s*{key}\s*:\s*(.+?)\s+\*+$'                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

print(getKey(s,pattern,'Key1'))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
value1
```

Answer (score 0):

So you could sub out the starts and ends with a regex like (where `s` is the whole string):

```
re.sub(r'^[\*\s]+(.*?)[\*\s]+$', r'\1', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

to get rid for the asterisks and spaces on the ends of the line. After this you can split each line with:

```
re.split(r':\s+', line, 1)
```

This will fail for lines with out `:`, which you can catch. So something like:

```
import re

lines = re.sub(r'^[\*\s]+(.*?)[\*\s]+$', r'\1', s, flags=re.MULTILINE).split('\n')
d = {}
for line in lines:
    try:
        key, value = re.split(r':\s+', line, 1)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    value = value.split(',')
    d[key] = value
```

Gives a `d` with:

```
{'Key1': ['value1'],
 'Key2': ['Thu', ' 06.02.2020 22:28:22'],
 'Key3': ['Sep 30 2019-02:35:32'],
 'key4': ['dc960e6', ' ttt: 35044b5'],
 'Key5': ['Value5'],
 'Key6': ['Value6']}
```

Comment: tnx will try it

Answer (score 0):

It can be parsed with an one-liner, no regexp. Input variable is `text`.

```
dct = {key: [v.strip() for v in value.split(',')] for key, sep, value in (line.strip(' *').partition(':') for line in text.splitlines()) if sep == ':'}
```

The same code formatted sanely:

```
dct = {
    key: [v.strip() for v in value.split(',')]
    for key, sep, value in (
        line.strip(' *').partition(':')
        for line in text.splitlines())
    if sep == ':'
    }
```

Output dict:

```
{'Key1': ['value1'], 'Key2': ['Thu', '06.02.2020 22:28:22'], 'Key3': ['Sep 30 2019-02:35:32'], 'key4': ['dc960e6', 'ttt: 35044b5'], 'Key5': ['Value5'], 'Key6': ['Value6']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the value returned by the [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) function to a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) object:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint
r = r'^\*+\s*(\w+)\s*:\s*(.+?)\s+\*+$'
txt = '''
**********************************************************************
*********                                                    *********
*********     llgalfaslfjasljflksjaglajlgjlajlgfaslg         *********
*********                                                    *********
********* Key1:            value1                            *********
*********                                                    *********
********* Key2: Thu, 06.02.2020 22:28:22                     *********
*********                                                    *********
********* Key3:           Sep 30 2019-02:35:32               *********
*********                  key4: dc960e6, ttt: 35044b5       *********
*********                                                    *********
********* Key5:         Value5                               *********
*********                                                    *********
********* Key6:    Value6                                    *********
*********                                                    *********
**********************************************************************
'''
res = {k: [v.strip() for v in vv.split(',')] for k, vv in re.findall(r, txt, re.M)}
pprint(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Key1': ['value1'],
 'Key2': ['Thu', '06.02.2020 22:28:22'],
 'Key3': ['Sep 30 2019-02:35:32'],
 'Key5': ['Value5'],
 'Key6': ['Value6'],
 'key4': ['dc960e6', 'ttt: 35044b5']}
```